# XSL Row append in empty space

Tags: xslt, formatting, rows, xsl-fo

I have a table with 3 columns and 2 rows.

**In the 1st row**:  That first column drops down to the entire page, and the 2nd and 3rd columns only drop an inch.

**In the 2nd Row**:  There are only two columns that use the middle and right columns.  This currently gets added to the 2nd page.

Right now that 2nd row is appended below where the **1st** column in the **1st** row end.  Is it possible in xsl 1.1 to have that 2nd row append below where the **2nd** and **3rd** columns are in the **1st** column [aka added in the white space on the first page]?

Answer (score 1):

Quickly refreshing my memory on xsl-fo, i quite quickly found this:

```
<fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="2">
```

When applied to your first cel in your first ro in your first column, it should then span two rows, meaning that the data on your second row appear next to it.

Comment: oerkelens, when I set that to the first cell in the first row it throws this: `The column-number or number of cells in the row overflows the number of fo:table-columns specified for the table.`

Comment: That might be because in your second row you still insert a cell in column 1. In your second row, make sure you only have 2 cells (or 1 cell which spans two rows.